# I wish to check if the second picture in my div has the given class...?

Tags: jquery

This is how I check if the first image on the page has the class:

```
$("img").first().hasClass('happy')
```

I have a div, and wish to check the second image in it for a class. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eq()` to get a specific element contained in a set.

```
$("div").find("img:eq(1)").hasClass("happy");
```

Note: it's zero-based, so the second element is index `1`.

Comment: What if my div has a class?

Comment: You can use whatever selector you require - I just used `div` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.my-class img:eq(1)").hasClass('happy');
```

[Here is the jquery doc for it.](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$("img").eq(1).hasClass('happy')
```

Note that the first element is accessed using `eq(0)` and the second one using `eq(1)`.